# VirtualQueryEx returning ERROR_BAD_LENGTH (Python)

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm trying to execute the [VirtualQueryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) function but am getting error 24 (ERROR_BAD_LENGTH) and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is my code (only including the necessary parts).

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes.wintypes import *


SIZE_T = ct.c_size_t
PVOID = LPVOID


class MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION(ct.Structure):
    _fields = (
        ("BaseAddress", PVOID),
        ("AllocationBase", PVOID),
        ("AllocationProtect", DWORD),
        ("PartitionId", WORD),
        ("RegionSize", SIZE_T),
        ("State", DWORD),
        ("Protect", DWORD),
        ("Size", DWORD),
    )


k32 = ct.WinDLL('kernel32')
VirtualQueryEx = k32.VirtualQueryEx
VirtualQueryEx.argtypes = HANDLE, LPCVOID, ct.POINTER(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION), SIZE_T
VirtualQueryEx.restype = SIZE_T


info = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
# proch comes from an OpenProcess call and the starting address I chose is one I picked from CheatEngine for testing.
bytes_returned = VirtualQueryEx(proch, 0x1408E125, ct.byref(info), ct.sizeof(info))
if bytes_returned == 0:
    print(f"Error occurred: {k32.GetLastError()}")
else:
    print(bytes_returned)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I missed this but I put _fields instead of _fields_ in the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION class. After changing it, it works fine.